# ANT,как положить в созданный Jar, внешние библиотеки, например log4j и JUnit?

Tags: ant, eclipse, java, jar

Добрый день, не пойму как внешние библиотеки log4j.jar и junit.jar засунуть через ANT в мой jar, да так чтоб действительно заработало. Уже кидал в свой jar эти библиотеки с расширением jar но ничего не заработало, так как если открыть jar созданный в Eclipse то эти библиотеки как бы распакованы "org.apach....и тд." Может кто сталкивался?

вот build.xml как выглядит:
    <project name="Test" default="run" basedir=".">

```
        <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
        <property name="test.dir" value="test"/>
        <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
        <property name="classes.dir" value="build/classes"/>
        <property name="libJunit.dir" value="C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\" />
        <property name="libLog4j.dir" value="D:\Libs\java\log4j-1.2.17\apache-log4j-1.2.17\" />

        <path id="classpath.base"/> 
        <path id="classpath.test">
                    <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
                    <path refid="classpath.base" />
                    <fileset dir="${libJunit.dir}">
                                <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset dir="${libLog4j.dir}">
                                <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                                <include name="*.java"/>
                    </fileset>
        </path>

        <target name="make_dirs" description="Make some dirs">
                <delete file="${build.dir}/*.jar"/>
                <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
                <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
                <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="./src">
                        <include name="*.xml"/>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset dir="./src">
                        <include name="*.properties"/>
                    </fileset>
                </copy>
        </target>

        <target name="compile" description="compile java" depends="make_dirs">
                <javac destdir="${classes.dir}">
                        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
                        <src path="${test.dir}"/>
                        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
                </javac>
                <echo>Compilation Comleted!</echo>
        </target>

        <target name="make_jar" description="make jar file" depends="compile">
                <jar destfile="${build.dir}/Test.jar" filesetmanifest="merge">
                    <manifest>
                                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
                    </manifest>
                    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                                <include name="**/*.class"/>
                                <include name ="**/*.xml"/>
                                <include name ="**/*.properties"/>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset dir="${libLog4j.dir}">
                                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                    </fileset>
                </jar>
                <echo>Build JAR Comleted!</echo>
        </target>

        <target name="junit" depends="compile">             
                    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
                            <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
                            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
                            <test name="TestTime" />
                    </junit>
                     <echo>JUNIT TEST Comleted!</echo>
        </target>

        <target name="run" depends="make_jar">

        <java jar="${build.dir}/Test.jar" 
            fork="true">
        </java>
        </target>
        <!---<target name="all" description="Do the build" depends="make_jar"/>-->

</project>
```

Comment: решение проблемы через ж... это неправильно, а в некоторых ситуациях даже незаконно. лучше так не делать. вы должны таскать с собой ваш jar файл + все dependencies  


если у вас нет желания возится с dependencies используйте maven

Comment: 1.Что Вы имеете ввиду jar таскать собой?(просто конкретнее)
2.А что с зависимостями то не так, там не к чему придраться.
3.Как это может быть незаконно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть задачи: Вам нужно сначала распаковать third-party либы с помощью ant таска unzip, а затем собрать все классы вместе, распакованные и ваши с помощью таска jar.

Или я что-то не понял ?

Comment: да, я думаю unzip тут и нужен был)))
Я просто сделал по русски, в ручную распаковал архиватором jar либы, а потом таском copy скопировал их в jar и всё заработало))) Думаю чтоб не делать это в ручную нужно было использовать вашь unzip, ну чтож поделаешь уже так сделал и отправил на проверку))
Спасибо за ответ вам, masterMind!:-)